# Truncation When Casting Varchar to Decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert a `varchar` to a `decimal` in **SSMS**.

If I hard code a value, then the cast is successful. But if I try to use a variable, then the value is truncated. This also happens when using the `convert` function.

Why does this happen, and how can I use a variable to cast the `varchar` to it's correct `decimal`?

Example:

```
Select  Cast('3.24' As Decimal(4, 3));
Result: 3.24


Declare @Number Varchar = '3.24';
Select  Cast(@Number As Decimal(4, 3));
Result: 3.00

Declare @Number Varchar = '3.24';
Select Convert(decimal(4,3), @Number)
Result: 3.00
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to give `@Number` a length.  The default is 1, so it is only holding the first digit (3).

Try this:

```
Declare @Number Varchar(20) = '3.24';
Select  Cast(@Number As Decimal(4,2));
Result: 3.24
```

Comment: Oh wow thank you I feel really silly now. I'm still new to SQL.